# Obtaining a list of the keywords for C#

Tags: c#, keyword

Is there a programmatic way to determine the list of keywords for a particular version of C#?

What I'm after is a list so I can do syntax coloring.  I can read a hard coded list but if I can get them programatically then I don't need to worry about updating hte list for each new release,etc.

Comment: As a side note, while there still isn't a list of keywords, [there is currently a command to determine whether a given word *is* a keyword.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262659/is-there-a-programatic-way-to-identify-c-sharp-reserved-words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not as far as I know. I needed this recently - I just copied from the C# spec documents.

Also; note that some are *contextual* keywords ;-p

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no built in api to fetch the C# keywords.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a *programmatic* way but you can always use [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb(VS.71).aspx) as there are different links to each version of the framework and you can extrapolate the language version from that.