# Is there a programatic way to identify c# reserved words?

Tags: c#, code-generation

I'm looking for a function like

```
public bool IsAReservedWord(string TestWord)
```

I know I could roll my own by grabbing a reserve word list from MSDN. However I was hoping there was something built into either the language or .NET reflection that could be relied upon so I wouldn't have to revisit the function when I move to newer versions of C#/.NET.

The reason I'm looking for this is I'm looking for a safeguard in .tt file code generation.

Comment: Doubt that. One of reasons might be - there are context specific keywords.

Comment: ... although if you don't care about context, whether a string is a keyword is a pretty simple test.  I doubt if the effort to maintain such a test is anything beyond trivial.  Even MS can't manufacture versions of C# very fast.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
CSharpCodeProvider cs = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var test = cs.IsValidIdentifier("new"); // returns false
var test2 = cs.IsValidIdentifier("new1"); // returns true
```

Comment: Note that this will not protect you against accidentally creating identifiers which start with two underscores.  Make sure to avoid doing so.

Comment: @Brian I verified this in a C# application targeting .Net 4. `IsValidIdentifier` API is able to return false when I make following check for a reserved keyword which starts with two underscores `var test3 = cs.IsValidIdentifier("__arglist"); // returns false`. So I believe this API should be full proof in that sense.

Comment: @RBT: Double underscore prefixes are reserved for internal use and thus should never be used.  Microsoft doesn't always even document double underscore keywords.  I'll also note that contextual keywords are technically valid identifiers (and thus `IsValidIdentifier` marks them as OK), but using them is begging for trouble.  E.g., you probably shouldn't use `yield` as a variable name.  There are probably ways to generate ambiguous code if failing to block contextual keywords.

Comment: Agreed. In fact following line of code is crashing my VS 2010 since morning the moment I uncomment it. Simply outrageous :P `//var x = __arglist(49, 34, 54, 6, "asdfg");`

Answer (score 12):

The `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator` has an `IsKeyword(string)` method that does exactly that. However, the class is internal, so you have to use reflection to access it and there's no guarantee it will be available in future versions of the .NET framework. Please note that `IsKeyword` doesn't take care of different versions of C#.

The public method `System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeGenerator.IsValidIdentifier(string)` rejects keywords as well. The drawback is this method does some other validations as well, so other non-keyword strings are also rejected.

**Update:** If you just need to produce a valid identifier rather than decide if a particular string is a keyword, you can use **`ICodeGenerator.CreateValidIdentifier(string)`**. **This method takes care of strings with two leading underscores as well** by prefixing them with one more underscore. The same holds for keywords. Note that `ICodeGenerator.CreateEscapedIdentifier(string)` prefixes such strings with the `@` sign.

Identifiers startings with two leading underscores are reserved for the implementation (i.e. the C# compiler and associated code generators etc.), so avoiding such identifiers from your code is generally a good idea.

**Update 2:** The reason to prefer `ICodeGenerator.CreateValidIdentifier` over `ICodeGenerator.CreateEscapedIdentifier` is that `__x` and `@__x` are essentially the same identifier. The following won't compile:

```
int __x = 10;
int @__x = 20;
```

In case the compiler would generate and use a `__x` identifier, and the user would use `@__x` as a result to a call to `CreateEscapedIdentifier`, a compilation error would occur. When using `CreateValidIdentifier` this situation is prevented, because the custom identifier is turned into `___x` (three underscores).

Comment: Really great finding. Can you please help me with an example which can help me understand this statement `The drawback is this method does some other validations as well, so other non-keyword strings are also rejected.` Have you ever come across any such non-keyword string which was rejected by this API? It will be really interesting to know any one of them.

Answer (score 8):

> However I was hoping there was something built into either the language or .NET reflection that could be relied upon so I wouldn't have to revisit the function when I move to newer versions of C#/.NET.

Note that C# has never added a new **reserved** keyword since v1.0. Every new keyword has been an unreserved contextual keyword.

Though it is of course possible that we might add a new reserved keyword in the future, we have tried hard to avoid doing so.

For a list of all the reserved and contextual keywords up to C# 5, see

http://ericlippert.com/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords/

Answer (score 4):

```
    static System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider CSprovider = 
           Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("C#");

    public static string QuoteName(string name)
    {
        return CSprovider.CreateEscapedIdentifier(name);
    }

    public static bool IsAReservedWord(string TestWord)
    {
        return QuoteName(TestWord) != TestWord;
    }
```

Since the definition of `CreateEscapedIdentifier` is:

```
public string CreateEscapedIdentifier(string name)
{
    if (!IsKeyword(name) && !IsPrefixTwoUnderscore(name))
    {
        return name;
    }
    return ("@" + name);
}
```

it will properly identify `__` identifiers as reserved.

Comment: This doesn't work — `CreateEscapedIdentifier` won't escape strings with two leading underscores.

Comment: @Ondrej: Strings with two leading underscores are reserved, so I think it's perfectly valid.

Comment: @Gabe: Depends whether you want to avoid them to prevent conflicts with the implementation or not. From my point of view to satisfy “looking for a safeguard in .tt file code generation” `CreateEscapedIdentifier` isn't strong enough.

Comment: @Ondrej: The OP asked how to identify reserved words, and the C# language specification section 2.4.2 says "Identifiers containing two consecutive underscore characters (U+005F) are reserved for use by the implementation."

Comment: @Gabe: The OP's last sentence completely redefines what he's looking for. My original idea was also concerned about *identifying keywords*. However, he's looking for a method to ensure that a particular string is a valid identifier, i.e. adjust it if necessary.

The C# language specification you cited means that identifiers starting with two underscores should not be used in code authored by the developer. Hence it's a very good idea to avoid them, and thus `CreateEscapedIdentifier` just isn't strong enough.

Comment: @Ondrej: It looks like I misread your first comment, thinking it said "*will* escape". Now that I see that you think it *won't* escape double-underscore strings, I'm confused as to the point you're making.

Comment: @Gabe: My comments to your answer are esentially faulty. The problem was caused by my wrong reading of `CreateEscapedIdentifier`'s code. However, `CreateValidIdentifier` is still a better option — see my corrected and extended answer.